# How to use inbuilt tools in QGIS Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is it possible to incorporate inbuilt tools like, for eg: vector grid of Research tools in QGIS model builder ?

Comment: This link mentions using an existing function from fTools and incorporating it into the Processing Toolbox (which in turn should be available to use in Model Builder) although I haven't tried this myself: http://anitagraser.com/2012/12/11/expanding-sextantes-ftools-toolbox/

Comment: @saravanaganesh18, you might have more answers if you ask a more specific question relating to Create Grid - what you tried, what's not working for you!

Answer (score 1):

Some if not all ftools tools have been ported to Processing. You should find **Create grid** in the toolbox.

It's not possible to use the original ftools tools directly in the Modeler.

Comment: Yep. I've tried with Create Grid. But find i somewhat confusing to imply.